# Where to find the python list, dictionary methods implementation in windows?

Tags: python

My python files are located at `'C:\Users\<username>\anaconda3\'`

I have tried to check inside anaconda3 folder but I did not find the list, `dict` methods implementation, I am curious to know how those methods are implemented in python and what is the time complexity?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You're probably using CPython, which is implemented in C.  The source is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has many different implementations written in different languages. The most common one is [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython) (reference implementation of Python).

I'm not a C-programmer, but from what I understand the following is the implementation of dict:

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c

... and the following is the implementation of lists:

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c